# What does hitting the tab button do in terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal

In Terminal, if I hit  <kbd>tab</kbd>  twice, Terminal asks if I want to list all 1580 possibilities. What is this, and what is this used for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pressing 'Tab' in terminal autocompletes commands and/or paths. Pressing it twice while there are no any part of any command/path is entered proposes to you to show all possible commands.

Comment: Ohh yeah, I remember reading that somewhere before. Thanks!